# Detecting device motion using Javascript WITHOUT event listeners

Tags: javascript, motion-detection

I'm writing a browser extension for Firefox that needs to detect motion. While browsing for solutions I've come across many code snippets that use event listeners to detect motion like the one below:

```
  var onDeviceMotion = function (eventData) {
    console.log(eventData.acceleration);
    console.log(eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity);
    console.log(eventData.rotationRate);
    console.log(eventData.interval);
  }

  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', onDeviceMotion, false);
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to detect device motion without the use of event listeners like in the code above.

Comment: The real question is, why do you need to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to?